# Reload Gunicorn in Docker on HTML File Change/Conditional Django Debug Mode

Tags: django, docker, gunicorn

My application is SaaS based and allows users to customise their frontend HTML specific to their account (it's a store software), by giving them access to HTML and CSS files through a code editor in the browser.

It's using Docker Compose running Gunicorn as the entry point for the web container.

When the user makes changes to the HTML pages, the changes aren't reflected live. I understand that Gunicorn has the `--reload` flag and I've tried using this. Unfortunately for that command to work I need to enable Debug mode which is a no go. Plus, I don't want to reload the entire application, just only when HTML files change.

I ran the application outside of Docker on a separate VM with the `--reload-extra-file` Gunicorn command and was able to get it to reload, with Debug turned off.

Like this:

```
--reload --reload-extra-file /path/to/folder
```

However when I do this within the Docker container using this as the command in Docker Compose:

```
gunicorn --chdir /home/someDir MyApp.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --reload --reload-extra-file /path/to/folder
```

It doesn't work. If I change to Debug mode it does or if I reload the Docker container it does.

Is there a solution to do this with Gunicorn? Or is there a better way?

--

Update, I feel that the issue may not be with Docker, but instead with Django itself not doing a reload as `Debug = False`. Is there anyway to fool Django into Debug mode just for templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suspected, it wasn't Docker that was causing the issue. Templates in Django are cached when `Debug = False`. Instead of turning that to True, you can actually change your "Template Options" in your settings to stop Django caching templates only:

```
TEMPLATES = [
  {
      'OPTIONS': {
          'debug': True
      },
  },
]
```

Comment: this helped me out! I was wondering why it was suddenly not working.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout `volumes` option in docker-compose config file.

`The new volumes key mounts the project directory (current directory) on the host to /code inside the container, allowing you to modify the code on the fly, without having to rebuild the image.`

https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/#step-5-edit-the-compose-file-to-add-a-bind-mount

Comment: Does this not require debug mode to be enabled? See it says flask debug needs to be set?

Comment: No, id doesn't matter. Point is that when source gets changed docker image gets changed too in reference to source code. `fask` reference is in context with documentation which uses python web framework flask in docker container.

Comment: Okay, so if I only want to reload the docker container when the templates are changed, should I use something like:
`templates:/path/to/templates`

Comment: I haven't tried reloading only specific folder, but comman usecase is, which ever files get changed those files will be reloaded in container.   example  `volumes: - .:/mnt` which loads current directory files to `/mnt` dir in container

Comment: Tried both and still not working. Again, setting `DEBUG = True` makes it work but other than that it doesn't.

Comment: It makes me feel that it’s not working because of debug false. Is there a way to overcome that?

Comment: have you verified that changed files are getting reloaded on adding option `volumes` in `docker-compose.yml`?